# D3: Draw part of interpolated path with dashed stroke

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm drawing a simple interpolated line using D3.js (output as path). However, I want part of the path to have a dashed stroke if a boolean in a data point is set to true:

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqaHO.png)

[image]

An easy solution would be to just draw it with `<line>` segments instead - but that way I lose the interpolation.

Then I found [an example](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4163057) from mbostock, showing how to draw a gradient along a interpolated path. I modified it to just draw transparent path fills whenever the boolean was set to true and white fills when false - while my *old* path is all dashed.
That works (queue the above screenshot) - but by adding around thousand path elements to the DOM contra having only a single path.

It's not desirable with that many DOM elements, especially since I'm going to make more curves and the site needs to be mobile optimized. Am I missing a much simpler solution?

Wouldn't mind a modified version of mbostock's example doing the *heavy* calculations in advance, as long as the DOM output is simple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I prepared this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/2t28z/) for [another `SO` question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783718/is-it-possible-to-draw-dashed-links-only-for-child-to-child-nodes-of-tree-layout). Screenshot is here:

[image]

I think you have enough material there to devise a solution that fits your needs.

Take a look also at this page:

[SVG Path Styling](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_stroking.asp)

Comment: Thanks! I actually stumbled upon your example in another thread. I'm just not sure how to implement it since there's no parent/child relationsship. 

My current (simplfied) code: 

    var set = d3.svg.line()
     .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
        .y(function(d) { return scale(d.y); })
        .interpolate("basis");

And:

    var lines = canvas.append("path")
        .attr("d", set(opt.data))

The opt.data contains the boolean flag.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `stroke-dasharray` to add dashes in the stroke of the generated path in the right places. That would entail finding the proper dash lengths. This can be done by calling `pathElm.getPathLength()` on the path up to the point where you want it to start being dashed, and to where you want it to end.

Let's say path A that is the part that is before the dashes should start. Set the d attribute with that part and call `getPathLength()` on it. Let's call this length **a**.

Append the the part of the path that should be dashed to the d attribute, then call `getPathLength()` again. Let's call this length **b**.

Create a new path element with the remaining part of the path, then call `getPathLength()` on that. Let's call this length **c**.

Construct a `stroke-dasharray` property string something like this:

```
var a = getPathLengthA();
var b = getPathLengthB();
var c = getPathLengthC();
var dasharray = a + " ";
for(var usedlen = 0; usedlen < (b-a); ) {
  dasharray += "5 10 "; // just whatever dash pattern you need
  usedlen += 15; // add the dash pattern length from the line above
}
dasharray += c;
pathElement.style.strokeDasharray = dasharray;
```

Here's a [static example](http://jsfiddle.net/bsajc5nw/) of that.